# php copy and file exists function: can i use absolute locations

Tags: php

I am very new to php. I have a pdf file at the absolute location "/home/abc/def.pdf". I have a php code (displaypdf.php) in /var/www/html which looks like

```
<?php
 $pdfloc = $_GET['pdfl'];
 if (file_exists($pdfloc)){
     if (!copy($pdfloc, '/tmp/temp.pdf')) {
         echo " destination file not found";
     }
     else {
         echo " file copied";
     }
 }
 else {
     echo " source file not found";
 }
?>
```

when I do `http://localhost/displaypdf.php?pdfl="/home/abc/def.pdf"` it says "source file not found" but I do have the source file with `-rwxr-xr-x` permission. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't put quotes around your values passed via GET. That being said, you shouldn't do what you are trying to do at all.  It is a HUGE security vulnerability.

Comment: you can not use quotes in the url.

Comment: You are doing a risky thing, don't do it (avoid `GET`, can't trust it).

Comment: What you're doing is a huge security hole. Don't do it. That said, I suspect you've been saved from yourself by SeLinux, which will prevent this by default.

Comment: ok, so the problem essentially is I have a set of pdfs in my machine, say in the location '/home/abc/def'. I have to use php to display a particular pdf, when needed. I know to do this using django, but not using php. what would be a better way of doing this?